# Collection query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection which contains these values

```
'sales marketing|telemarketing',
```

what I'm trying to do is query/filter the items in collection but just based on the individual type so the for example value of 'telemarketing'. I have tried

`$results = $data->where('Department', 'contains', $type);` and also tried LIKE but because of the format with the pipe it's not picking the type/value.

This might be a dumb question but any ideas would be great!

Comment: If you have a collection of types, you can use a whereIn statement. More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: 6 => array:5 [
      "Employee" => "Some Company"
      "Name" => "John Something"
      "Usages" => "sales marketing|telemarketing"
      "StartDate" => "1st Mar 2021"
      "EndDate" => ""
    ]
  ]

Comment: thanks for the reply Ludo, I have tried withIn

Answer (score 0):

The where-method also can handle only two Parameters. For example:

```
$data= collect([
  ['Department' => 'sales', 'price' => 200],
  ['Department' => 'marketing', 'price' => 100],
  ['Department' => 'telemarketing', 'price' => 150],
  ['Department' => 'marketing', 'price' => 100],
]);

$departmentName = "marketing"; 

$results = $data->where('Department', $departmentName);

dd($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example:

```
[
  "Employee" => "Some Company",
  "Name" => "John Something",
  "Usages" => "sales marketing|telemarketing",
  "StartDate" => "1st Mar 2021",
  "EndDate" => ""
]
```

The main issue is that the "Usage" property is a string containing multiple values, with the pipe character acting as a separator.
One solution to filter by one of those values is by mapping your original collection to [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map) the string in an array with the [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method and then use the [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-filter) method to filter based on the Usages you're interested in.
The resulting code might look like this:

```
$mappedCollection = $collection->map(function($el) {
    $el['Usages'] = explode('|', $el['Usages']); // Transform the string into an array
    return $el;
});

$result = $mappedCollection->filter(function($el) {
    return in_array('sales marketing',$el['Usages']); // Change 'sales marketing' with the desired Usage
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I am trying to do though is the query comes in from a search and I just need to find that term in the collection (Usages) because the value is piped I cannot find it in the where clause. I don't need to change the array just find that value in Usages. So I'm looking to change it, just find it it in the where query

Comment: If you prefer to not change the structure of your array, you can simply use the filter method by creating the array by exploding the string in place like this:  

    `$result = $collection->filter(function($el) {`
        `return in_array('sales marketing', explode('|', $el['Usages']), true); // Change 'sales marketing' with the desired Usage`
    `});`

Comment: But that still won't help with the $filtered = $data->where('Usages', $type);. There must be a way to query a value in collection even when there is a pipe in the value? WhereIn doesn't. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, why is the usage of where a requirement for your case? The filter method allows for more customization with the filter you want to apply (in fact, where simply calls filter with predefined callbacks for the most common operations like equality, inequality etc... You also wanted to use the LIKE operator, but that's an operator available for use in the where method for query builder objects, not collections. Are you actually working with a collection or rather with a query builder instance?

Comment: Basically using simpleexcel to get a CSV upload, to collection then query it on the Usage type, on that field and return results but obviously the pipe not helping